# Separating HTML inside PHP to avoid errors

Tags: php, html

I've just started to study PHP at university and we've been given 10 exercises to do without any real aid we just have to figure it out for ourselves but I can't figure out how to make this work.

I've got a php page with a html table inside that has 10 boxes, in box 5 I have to make a form that allows you to input a four digit integer number or a four letter string and store it in a variable "$x". A user will put the numbers/letters in a box and click on a button labelled "submit" in order to enter the number/letter into the variable.

I made a form from a tutorial in a blank php page as a test and it worked but when I put it inside the HTML code (which is inside the php) I get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF, expecting ',' or ';' in Y:\xampp\htdocs\laboneformtest.php on line 33

Below is the code:

```
<tr>
<td><b>Rectangle 5: input field four digit integer number or four letter string and
store in variable x</b><br /><br />
"if (isset($_POST['name'])) $name = $_POST['name'];
else $name = "(Not Entered)";

echo "
Your name is: $name<br />
<form method="post" action="formtest.php">
What is your name?
<input type="text" name="name" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</td>
```

I realise the form isn't for variable $x yet I just wanted to get this working before I started on that.

Comment: is this the full file, if not please include the full file.

Comment: Boy, which line is line 33 ? (Included code is less than 20 lines)

Comment: First off, thanks for letting us know it's homework - you'll get +1's for mentioning that, though you might not get any straight up answers.

Comment: One comment, it's usually best practice to use enclosing braces `if (condition) { ... } else { ... }` with your if statements

Comment: -1: That is not the error that you get with this file, as this file contains no PHP segments.

Comment: You have quotes in your tags.  You need to escape them if you are going to echo them.

Answer (score 2):

PHP code blocks must be delimited with `<?php` and `?>` (if you've got short_tags turned on, `<?` will work as well.

There is no such thing as a PHP script - there are only files that have PHP code blocks within them, and `<?PHP ?>` is how you tell the PHP interpreter where it should start executing instead of just outputting.

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = $_POST[\"name"\];
} else {
    $name = '(Not Entered)';
}

echo "Your name is: $name<br />";
?>

<form>etc......</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    if( $_POST['name'] && $_POST['name'] != ""){
      $name = urldecode( $_POST['name'] );                
    }else{
      $name = "not set";
    }
?>

<table>
<tr>
 <td>
   <?=$name?>
 </td>
</tr>
</table> 
<form here>
```

Comment: Ok guys I just got this working it was a very simple/stupid mistake on my part.

I do have another question though, how do you go about so that the form can only be submitted using a four digit integer or four letter string? I imagine it has something to do with if statements

Comment: @gethin: look into the [strlen()](http://php.net/strlen) function. And incidentally, you can do quick function docs searches on the PHP site by entering `php.net/funcname` as an address (e.g. php.net/strlen).